# OnHistoryStateUpdated filter not working as expected

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm working on a Firefox add-on where I would like to add a [pageAction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/pageAction) when you are watching a video in YouTube. My [background script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension#Background_scripts) works well until you go from a YouTube video to any other YouTube page, the pageAction doesn't disappear. This is my code:

```
var filter = {
  url:[
    {
      pathContains: "watch",
      hostSuffix: "youtube.com"
    }
  ]
}
function showPageAction(details) {
  browser.pageAction.show(details.tabId);
}

browser.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(showPageAction, filter);
browser.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(showPageAction, filter);
```

It just happens the first time you press any other YouTube link from a YouTube video page (history, main, channel, etc), because when you go to another YouTube page from that first click, it disappears.
Something like:

1. Open new tab
2. Go directly to www.youtube.com (doesn´t appear)
3. Press any video (it appears, as expected)
4. Press any other link to a YouTube page (main, history, a cannel) (it's still there, shoudn't disappear?)
5. Press again any other link different from a video (it finally disappears)

I was thinking to add a filter in the showPageAction function but, isn't the filter of the onHistoryStateUpdated supposed to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter works as expected; it's the default resetting behavior that doesn't.

The point of history state update based navigation is that no *actual* navigation happens (unlike `onCommitted` events). That means FF doesn't hide it automatically.

Which means you have to take care of it on navigations that result in non-watch pages.

Your best bet is to filter within the listener:

```
// Since history manipulation must preserve origin,
//  you can limit to YouTube domains for performance
const hostFilter = {
  url: [{hostSuffix: "youtube.com"}]
}

function updatePageAction(details) {
  if (details.url.includes("watch")) {
    browser.pageAction.show(details.tabId);
  } else {
    browser.pageAction.hide(details.tabId);
  }
}

browser.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(
  updatePageAction,
  hostFilter
);
```

Comment: I didn't really get the explanation, sorry (english isn't my first language). But the code really works well just with a change. 
I tried with contains and it didn't work and according to [onHistoryUpdate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation/onHistoryStateUpdated) docs, url is a string; and there is no `contains` method in string but `includes` has the same result.
With that change, you don't even need the onCommitted event.